# Data abstraction or Data Connector framework for Java

Tags: java, connector

Note:There is a good chance I'm not using the correct terminology here and that maybe the reason I'm not finding the answers to my question. I apologize upfront if this has been already answered, so please just direct me there.

I am looking for an open source framework written in Java that would allow me to build pluggable data connectors (and obviously have some built in already) and almost have a query language (abstraction layer) that would translate into any of those connections.

For example: I would be able to say:
Fetch 1 record from a Mongo DB that matches name='John Doe'
and get JSON as a response
or I could say
Fetch all records from a MySQL DB that matches name='John Doe'
and get a JSON as a response

If not exactly what I described, I am willing to work with anything that would have a part of this solved.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to find a "Swiss army knife" data abstraction framework that does all of the above.  Perhaps the closest things to what you ask for would be JPA providers for both Mongo and MySQL (Hibernate is a well-regarded JPA provider for MySQL, and a quick google search shows Kundera, DataNucleus and Hibernate OGM for Mongo).  This will let you map your data to Java Objects, which might be a step further than what you ask for since you explicitly asked for JSON; however, there are numerous options for mapping the resulting objects into JSON if you need to present JSON to a user or another system (Jackson comes to mind for this).

Answer (score 0):

Try [YADA](http://github.com/Novartis/YADA), an open source data-abstraction framework.

From the README:

> YADA is like a Universal Remote Control for data.
>
> For example, what if you could access
>
> any data set
>   at any data source
>   in any format
>   from any environment
>   using just a URL
>   with just one-time configuration?
>   You can with YADA.
>
> Or, what if you could get data
>   from multiple sources
>   in different formats
>   merging the results
>   into a single set
>   on-the-fly
>   with uniform column names
>   using just one URL?
>   You can with YADA.

Full disclosure: I am the creator of YADA.